Node works in Powershell but not Ubuntu
When I run node -v in PowerShell I get v22.11.0 but when I run the same command in Ubuntu I get Command 'node' not found.

npm -v works for both.
Ubuntu was installed as part of the WSL installation. Which I installed after I had already installed Node
nodejs folder is in the path environment variable.
the only difference between npm and Node is npm is installed in my user account and Node is installed system-wide

Why would the same command on the same computer work for PowerShell but not Ubuntu? Is this anything to worry about or normal functionality?

Note that if an executable is only discoverable via $PATH on the Windows side of things, i.e. if you're looking to invoke an *.exe file located in the Windows file system, you must include the file-name extension, i.e. node.exe -v in your case.
